# maxWidth uncenters dialog box (modal) for material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set the `max-width` on `material-ui`'s `Dialog` component. When I set the max width, the modal becomes uncentered. I have created a minimal example here:

```
//npm install material-ui
import React from 'react'
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

function App() {
  return(
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
        <Dialog open={true} style={{maxWidth: '300px'}}>
          <h2>nice box</h2>
        </Dialog>
        <h1>React App</h1>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

If I remove the `style={{maxWidth: '300px'}}`, the the `Dialog` component and its children are centered as expected.

[image]

How can I put a maxWidth on the Dialog component and have it still be centered *properly*? I've tried playing around with it quite a bit without much luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. I should have been using the `contentStyle` prop on the `Dialog` component. Fixed example looks like this:

```
//npm install material-ui
import React from 'react'
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

function App() {
  return(
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
        <Dialog open={true} contentStyle={{maxWidth: 300}}>
          <h2>nice box</h2>
        </Dialog>
        <h1>React App</h1>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App
```

Thanks